# how can I see the current element that represents a bar to which the hovering is applied

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a chart in which hovering shows all the elements represented by bars, but they are too many and this produces problems such as the appearance of a scrollbar.

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to show only the current bar that is hovering. In the c3.js documentation I see that this property exists to change the content of the tooltip, but I don't know how to get the current bar to which it is hovering.

With this:

```
tooltip: {

        contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
            console.log(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
            return "fds";
}
```

this is my live code:

```
var query = [
    ["x", "Usuarios"],
    ["Berta Arroyave", 53],
    ["Rogelio Zuluaga", 52],
    ["Manrique Perez", 42],
    ["Justin Vargas", 33],
    ["Believer qw", 28],
    ["María Jimenez", 14],
    ["Nairo Quintan", 12],
    ["Adriana Cardona", 11],
    ["Departamento Idio", 9],
    ["Natalia Benjumea", 7],
    ["Bibliotecatos", 7],
    ["Jose Herrera", 7],
    ["Doralibia", 6],
    ["Secretaría General  ", 6],
    ["Natalia Ochoa", 6],
    ["Viviana Cano", 5],
    ["Erika Valencia", 5],
    ["Sandra Cañon", 3],
    ["Lina Constanza Suaza", 3],
    ["Recepción User", 2],
    ["Facultad Medicina  ", 2],
    ["Sandra Valencia", 2],
    ["Luz Sepulveda", 2],
    ["Heidy Zapata", 2],
    ["Gabriela García", 2],
    ["Auxiliar Administrativo", 2],
    ["Adriana Mejia", 2],
    ["Administrador", 1],
    ["Nathaly", 1]
  ]

  c3.generate({
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: query,

      type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category' // this needed to load string x value
      }
    }
 });
```

how can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/50uej3at/

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that your data is in the wrong format to what you appear to be aiming for... rather than having one entry per category you've got one category with everything as an entry within it...

If you put this line after your query data definition:

```
query = d3.transpose(query);
```

You should get one bar per person and no massive tooltips

https://jsfiddle.net/yta1s9cz/1/

(I also adjusted the axis label rotation to make the labels readable)